# How to install software from media to remote server?

Tags: dedicated-hosting

I will be renting a virtual or dedicated server (might be Amazon EC2 or from SoftLayer). I was wondering what is the best way to install software from CD to the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into an ISO and upload the ISO to the server, then mount it there.